# How do I use Bootstrap when I don't have 12 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap on my site but what do I do in situations where columns simply don't add up to 12?

For example, I have 2 rows, each with 4 columns.  However, the final column is going to be there to describe waterfront property.  If the property isn't on the water, I don't want there to be a column there on the second row.

[An example of what I mean](http://listingnaples.com/properties/215010951/13650-pondview-cir-naples-fl-34119).  If I don't want that last column that says "Waterfront Features" as an example, how would I code it?

Comment: So you want the divs to span across the whole thing when "Waterfront Features" isn't present?

Comment: I think ideally there would just be 3 across on that row.  Another example though are the pictures.  How do you use Bootstrap properly if you have different number of pictures in a gallery?

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have? You don't need to fill 12 columns.

Comment: So for example if you hide the 1st column(Waterfront description) based on some condition(you have to do that by JavaScript), your markup will automatically adjust itself and all columns will shift one space left and if it is the last column(Waterfront features), your page will remain same with just an empty portion at the last column of 2nd row. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

For four columns you can define 3 column space, if the waterfront is not there then you can either leave that area blank or define that particular row with 4 column space. 
You can apply the same in pictures for your gallery.

Example:-

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <!-- If waterfront is not there don't add. Leave it blank. Otherwise define this row as col-lg-4 -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that and then shrink to smaller sizes, it does not wrap properly.  It is almost as if things don't clear properly.

Comment: Try adding col-md-3, col-sm-3, col-xs-3 for smaller screen sizes